# How to get windows service name from app.config

Tags: c#, windows-services

i have a app.config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ServiceName" value="HasService"/>
    <add key="ServiceDisplayName" value="HasService"/>
  </appSettings>
```

my service installer class

```
 [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class MyServiceInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public MyServiceInstaller()
        {
            var process = new ServiceProcessInstaller {Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem};
            var serviceAdmin = new ServiceInstaller
            {
                StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual,
                ServiceName = "HasService",
                DisplayName = "HasService"
            };
            Installers.Add(process);
            Installers.Add(serviceAdmin);
        }
    }
```

i want to get service name from app.config.

```
    var serviceAdmin = new ServiceInstaller
    {
        StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual,
        ServiceName = GetServiceNameAppConfig("ServiceName"),
        DisplayName = GetServiceNameAppConfig("ServiceDisplayName")
    };

    public string GetServiceNameAppConfig(string serviceName)
    {
        //what should i write here?
    }
```

how to get service name and service display name from app.config file in MyServiceInstaller class.

Comment: why would you want to do this? I can see an argument for putting "stuff that might change one day" into the config file, but would you seriously put the name of a service in this category? Also you can change the config file as much as you want, but unless you reinstall the service (i.e. unless MsServiceInstaller does its stuff) you won't actually change the service name. This could potentially be confusing for someone to have to maintain.

Comment: @Pete i want to run the service with two different names.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

problem is solved with this code

```
public string GetServiceNameAppConfig(string serviceName)
{
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyServiceInstaller)).Location);
    return config.AppSettings.Settings[serviceName].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this - `configurationmanager.appsettings["yourkey"]`

Comment: i use ConfigurationManager when windows service is installed an error occurs. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the ta
rget of an invocation.
The inner exception System.ArgumentException was thrown with the following error
 message: Service name  contains invalid characters, is empty, or is too long (m
ax length = 80)..

Comment: Check this it will help you out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030416/setup-project-custom-installer-connection-string